# Error with Parameter: the sqlparametercollection only accepts non-null sqlparameter type objects not sqlparameter[] objects

Tags: vb.net

I have the below code and I am facing a hard time with the parameter... I'm getting the below error:

> the sqlparametercollection only accepts non-null sqlparameter type objects not sqlparameter[] objects

When I insert a msgbox to check the value of `param(0).value` I get MARC as an example.

Should I create a parameter for every `rowData.item(i)` too?

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=USER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=SSPI"
con.Open()
cmd.Connection = con
Try
Dim InsertCommand As New SqlCommand
Dim param(0) As SqlClient.SqlParameter
param(0) = New SqlParameter("abrev", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
param(0).Value = UCase(abrev)

InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(param)

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO allData (ABRV, Times, Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Num5) VALUES (param,rowData.Item(0),rowData.Item(1),rowData.Item(2),rowData.Item(3),rowData.Item(4),rowData.Item(5))"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
                Finally
                    con.Close()
                End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you're using 2 different variables: `InsertCommand` and `cmd`

```
InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(param)

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO allData (ABRV, Times, Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Num5) VALUES (param,rowData.Item(0),rowData.Item(1),rowData.Item(2),rowData.Item(3),rowData.Item(4),rowData.Item(5))"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Another problem is the parameter does not match. You use the parameter named `abrev`

```
param(0) = New SqlParameter("abrev", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
```

In your insert statement, you should have the parameter `@abrev`

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO allData (ABRV, Times, Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Num5) VALUES (@abrev,rowData.Item(0),rowData.Item(1),rowData.Item(2),rowData.Item(3),rowData.Item(4),rowData.Item(5))"
```

> Should i create a parameter for every rowData.item(i) too ?

Yes, you should. Do it similarly to the `abrev` parameter.
Hope you get it work soon.

Comment: You pointed it out to me... I fixed it with the below code:
`Dim InsertCommand As New SqlCommand
cmd.Parameters.Add("@abrev", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = abrev
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO allData "INSERT INTO allData (ABRV, Times, Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Num5) VALUES (@abrev,rowData.Item(0),rowData.Item(1),rowData.Item(2),rowData.Item(3),rowData.Item(4),rowData.Item(5))"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: Creating now the parameters for rowdata.item(i), Thanks a lot !